# WebAPI route configuration for multiple HttpPost's with different actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am NOT trying to do REST. I want this:

```
public class MyV2Controller 
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<UserModel> Action1([FromBody] FirstModel firstModel)
    { }

    [HttpPost]
    public Task<UserModel> Action2([FromBody] SecondModel secondModel)
    { }
}
```

The routes should line up to this:

```
http://localhost:1234/api/v2/my/action1/

http://localhost:1234/api/v2/my/action2/
```

I have tried many different route configurations (including various combinations of attribute routing), but nothing seems to work. How might I make this work?

Comment: how do you call this from the client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Using Route attribute

[RoutePrefix("api/v2/my")]
public class MyV2Controller 
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("action1")]
    public Task<UserModel> Action1([FromBody] FirstModel firstModel)
    { }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("action2")]
    public Task<UserModel> Action2([FromBody] SecondModel secondModel)
    { }
}
```

Comment: I kept trying to add the {firstModel} and {secondModel} parameters to the route attribute. As your answer points out, they're not needed. Thanks!